# Stop event dropping in previous dates fullcalendar react

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am working on react project and using react version [full calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullcalendar/react) and I want to stop event dropping in previous dates how can I do that?

```
<FullCalendar
  ref={this.calendarRef}
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  headerToolbar={{
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  }}
  initialView='dayGridMonth'
  editable={true}
  selectable={true}
  selectMirror={true}
  dayMaxEvents={true}
  weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
  initialEvents={this.state.events}
  select={this.dateSelectHandle}
  eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
  eventClick={(event) => this.handleEventClick(event)}
  validRange={start: new Date()}
  eventsSet={this.handleEvents} // called after events are initialized/added/changed/removed
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [visibleRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange) and [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) for full calendar to allow user to select a date within the range, in this way the user will not be able to select a previous date.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but how can I use in react ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in react

Comment: @VarinderSohal use it just like the other callback options you've specified (e.g. eventsSet, select etc)

Comment: @VarinderSohal why, which bit are you stuck with exactly? The documentation contains examples for validRange code, and your own code above has examples of how to set an option to run a function. What have you tried, and what went wrong so far?

Comment: @MuhammadAsad I have one more query. I used before validRange as per your recommendation but it also hides the previous dates and events. I want to show previous dates events but not allowed to drag and drop in those dates. how can I do that?

Comment: Hi,
There's a method to dates. Please try to use filters and moment, Also you can override the render method of the events in which you can customise the way you want to render what to make active and what to make in active